# create text file after publish product with hooks

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

i want make text file with subject and title product with woocommerce hooks
but not work

```
function my_project_updated_save_file( $woocommerce_new_product ) 
{
    $id = $product->get_id();

            $product->set_props( array(
                'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
                'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
            ) );

    $post_title = $product.name;
    $post_url = $product.slug;

        $content = $post_title;
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.txt","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$content);
        fclose($fp);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'my_project_updated_save_file' );
```

Comment: first of all $post_object is not defined and this will save only variable products not simple products

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: you are using  $post_object->post_title but it was not initiated in the function

Comment: this is my frist webhook i do't know can you help me ? can you type code?

Comment: replace $woocommerce_new_product with $post_object

Comment: i replace $woocommerce_new_product with $post_object but not work